# Jquery plugin for Complex tags kind of Input Box

Tags: jquery, tagging

What would be the best way for me to implement a text box, which has individual tag words surrounded by boxes with a small X button to remove tags. I have seen this in softwares like JIRA to add tags to your issue. Would be great if there was a Jquery-UI plugin already doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.jquery.wisdomplug.com/jquery-plugins/facebook-jquery-plugins/fcbkcomplete/